# Project Euler 12, very slow in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

So you need to find the first triangle number which has over 500 divisors. I have found a working method which finds the prime factors and multiplies the exponents but it takes a very long time. How can I speed it up?

```
Function divisors(ByVal c As Long) As Integer
    Dim j, k As Integer
    Dim d As Long = c
    Dim factors As New List(Of Integer)
    For i As Long = 2 To c / 2 + 1
        If d Mod i = 0 Then
            If i Mod 2 = 0 And i <> 2 Then
                i = i / 2
            End If
            factors.Insert(k, i)
            d = d / i
            i = 2
            k += 1
        End If
    Next
    j = 1
    For i As Integer = 0 To factors.Count - 1
        j = j * factors(i)
    Next
    If j <> c Then
        factors.Add(2)
    End If
    factors.Add(factors.Max + 1)
    factors.Sort()
    Dim count, num1, totfactor As Integer
    Dim totfactors As New List(Of Integer)
    For Each num As Integer In factors
        If num1 <> num Then
            totfactor = count
            If totfactor <> 0 Then totfactors.Add(totfactor)
            totfactor = 0
        End If
        If num1 <> num Then count = 0
        For i As Integer = 0 To c
            If num = i Then
                count += 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        num1 = num
    Next
    Dim total As Integer = 1
    For Each num As Integer In totfactors
        total = total * (num + 1)
    Next
    Return total
End Function
Sub Main()
    Dim number As Long = 153
    Dim pos As Integer = 18
    Do
        number = number + pos
        Console.WriteLine("number:" & number & " divisors:" & divisors(number))
        pos += 1
    Loop Until divisors(number) > 500
End Sub
```

Comment: What was your thinking behind the upper limit `For i As Long = 2 To c / 2 + 1`?

Comment: I wanted to reduce the no. of values it had to search, starting at 2 because 1 is a nuisance to (c/2) + 1. I didnt want it to round down below half the original number but go 1 above it.

Comment: Well, you actually only need to go to the square root.

Comment: I saw that on someones code in python, but didnt understand the maths behind it, could you explain?

Comment: It now runs like a charm, thanks a lot but could you explain why?

Comment: Briefly, for a number `x`, if `a` is a divisor then `x / a` is also a divisor. Without loss of generality you only need to consider the case where `a` is less than equal to `x / a`. Hence the square root limit.

Comment: Ok, I understand the logic there with only considering a being less than x/a but why is the square root the limit?

Comment: I feel I should add that this kind of question belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim j, k As Integer
Dim d As Long = c
Dim factors As New List(Of Integer)
For i As Long = 2 To c / 2 + 1
    If d Mod i = 0 Then
        If i Mod 2 = 0 And i <> 2 Then
            i = i / 2
        End If
        factors.Insert(k, i)
        d = d / i
        i = 2
        k += 1
    End If
Next
```

`factors.Insert(k, i)` is always followed by `k += 1`, so this is a long way of writing `factors.Add(i)`. Drop `k`, and don’t declare `j` until you need it.

```
Dim d As Long = c
Dim factors As New List(Of Integer)
For i As Long = 2 To c / 2 + 1
    If d Mod i = 0 Then
        If i Mod 2 = 0 And i <> 2 Then
            i = i / 2
        End If
        factors.Add(i)
        d = d / i
        i = 2
    End If
Next
```

All these `/`s are floating-point division. Use `\` for integer division. Turn `Option Strict On`. Also, shorthand, because it’s nice.  Setting `i = 2` at the end of the `For` with `i` as its loop variable also does nothing, so drop that.

```
Dim d As Long = c
Dim factors As New List(Of Integer)
For i As Long = 2 To c \ 2 + 1
    If d Mod i = 0 Then
        If i Mod 2 = 0 And i <> 2 Then
            i \= 2
        End If
        factors.Add(i)
        d \= i
    End If
Next
```

I guess the innermost `If` was added because your code didn’t get prime factors, but that’s not the way to fix that bug. Remove it for now.

```
Dim d As Long = c
Dim factors As New List(Of Integer)
For i As Long = 2 To c \ 2 + 1
    If d Mod i = 0 Then
        factors.Add(i)
        d \= i
    End If
Next
```

Okay, now we’re down to something that’s stuck halfway between getting prime factors (`d \= i`) and getting all divisors. Continuing with your original prime factor plan: since a prime factor can appear more than once, you need to keep looping while it divides your number.

```
Dim d As Long = c
Dim factors As New List(Of Integer)

For i As Long = 2 To c \ 2 + 1
    While d Mod i = 0
        d \= i
        factors.Add(i)
    End While
Next
```

Now the outer loop can stop a heck of a lot earlier.

```
Dim d As Long = c
Dim i As Long = 2
Dim factors As New List(Of Integer)

While d >= i
    While d Mod i = 0
        d \= i
        factors.Add(i)
    End While

    i += 1
End While
```

You can also optimize this a bit by doing the inside of the loop with `i = 2`, then starting at `i = 3` and moving by twos with `i += 2`. There’s a better way, though, which I’ll get to. Moving on.

```
j = 1
For i As Integer = 0 To factors.Count - 1
    j = j * factors(i)
Next
If j <> c Then
    factors.Add(2)
End If
```

This… multiplies all the factors back together to undo the incorrect prime fix. Remove entirely.

```
factors.Add(factors.Max + 1)
factors.Sort()
```

What’s this `Add` for? Also, with the bug fixed, they’re already sorted.

```
Dim count, num1, totfactor As Integer
Dim totfactors As New List(Of Integer)
For Each num As Integer In factors
    If num1 <> num Then
        totfactor = count
        If totfactor <> 0 Then totfactors.Add(totfactor)
        totfactor = 0
    End If
    If num1 <> num Then count = 0
    For i As Integer = 0 To c
        If num = i Then
            count += 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    num1 = num
Next
Dim total As Integer = 1
For Each num As Integer In totfactors
    total = total * (num + 1)
Next
```

I’m just going to skip trying to understand this part. Rest assured that it is extremely slow because it loops from 0 to c to confirm that the factor `num` is an integer less than c… which will always be the case. To get the number of divisors of a number based on its prime factorization, multiply together one plus the count of each prime factor:

```
Dim last As Integer = -1
Dim count As Integer = 0
Dim result As Integer = 1

For Each num As Integer In factors
    If num = last Then
        count += 1
    Else
        result *= count + 1
        last = num
        count = 1
    End If
Next

Return result * (count + 1)
```

All this should take the time complexity from Θ(N²) to O(N). You can get the answer from here, and note that it doesn’t need a `Long`. Now, folding this into other loop, because you can count distinct prime factors and find them at the same time:

```
Function Divisors(c As Integer) As Integer
    Dim d As Integer = c
    Dim i As Integer = 2
    Dim result As Integer = 1

    While d >= i
        Dim count As Integer = 1

        While d Mod i = 0
            d \= i
            count += 1
        End While

        result *= count
        i += 1
    End While

    Return result
End Function
```

Finally, stop doubling the time required to check a given number by calling `divisors` in both `Console.WriteLine` and `Loop Until`:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim number As Integer = 153
    Dim pos As Integer = 18

    Do
        number += pos
        pos += 1
    Loop Until Divisors(number) > 500

    Console.WriteLine(number)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to do that, it really helps me to see the inefficiences of my code. I was multiplying the count of each prime factor + 1 in the list to get total divisors but one of the things that took me the longest was figuring out how to find the total count of each prime in the list which is also what the factors.add is for. Can you show me an easier way of doing that?

Comment: @t.juricic See the complete `Function Divisors` at the bottom – the easiest way is not to have a list at all and instead make use of where you already have a loop for each group of divisors. I’d like to have associated that with your original approach without the inner loop, but that one doesn’t work… you can also loop to the number itself for an extremely easy solution, but that doesn’t involve primes at all.